# Spring Data Rest does not support post for item resource according to docs, but it does?

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/3.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#repository-resources.item-resource

According to that, the only methods supported for a single item resource are GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE.

But I created a simple resource with an example project and it accepts POST for a single resource. Why?

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't. The [RepositoryEntityController](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-rest/blob/3.2.x/spring-data-rest-webmvc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/rest/webmvc/RepositoryEntityController.java) class is responsible for handling the repository endpoints, and there is no POST endpoit for `BASE_MAPPING + "/{id}"` in it.

Are you sure you didn't create any custom endpoints?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem using MongoRepository: on a single item resource, POST operations returned 200, although the body showed an error message.

I solved the problem by removing **getter** and **setter** methods from the **id** field.